# top-k largest element from the max heap

Tags: performance, algorithm, max-heap

I am a mechanical student and I have changed my field to Computers. Need to get through the algorithms class. This question is one of the exercise questions

1. If the max heap algorithm's running time is  O(klogn) then is there any algorithm which has better running time than this?

Comment: like i said the running time is O(klogn) but is there any algorithm which has a better running time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Print and remove the root `k` times;
2. `O(k log n)`;
3. [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650917/oklogk-time-algorithm-to-find-kth-smallest-element-from-a-binary-heap).

Comment: can u please tell me which algorithm will be better and what is the running time for that?

Comment: @user2798432 - `O(k log k)` will be better, it's described in my link.