# O(k) algorithm to find kth min element from a min heap

Tags: algorithm, heap, time-complexity

o(klogn) solution is trivial to find the kth minimum.And here [O(klogk) time algorithm to find kth smallest element from a binary heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650917/oklogk-time-algorithm-to-find-kth-smallest-element-from-a-binary-heap)  is a O(klogk) solution. But i was thinking of an algo which could be o(k) if correct . From the min heap,take the first k elements(first k nodes,traverse level wise ) and store them in an array .Now max heapify this array bottom-up which would take o(k) time.The root of this heap would be the required answer.Can anyone see a flaw in this algorithm?

Comment: The flaw is that the first k elements in the min heap may not be the k smallest (otherwise that would mean that the array is completely sorted).

Answer (score 3):

Consider this example

```
        1
    2       11
  3   4   12  13
```

If you want to get the 3rd min element, it wouldn't be in the 3 first nodes.