# Implement an iterator on a binary heap

Tags: iterator, heap, binary-heap

I am looking for a way to implement an iterator on binary heaps (maximum or minimum).

That is, by using it’s nextNode() function for the i-th time, can get the i-th (greater or smaller) element in the heap.

Note that this operation happens without actually extracting the heap’s root!

My initial thoughts were:

- Actually extract i elements, push them into a stack, and then insert them back into the heap after getting the i-th value. This takes O(i*log(n)) for each function call.
- Keep an auxiliary sorted data structure, which can allow to lookup the next value in O(1), however updates would take O(n).

I understand these approaches eliminate the benefits of using heaps, so I’m looking for a better approach.

Comment: I think this is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650917/oklogk-time-algorithm-to-find-kth-smallest-element-from-a-binary-heap - you don't have to spend O(i) for operations on the sorted auxiliary structure.

Comment: Do you need your iterator to remain valid when the heap changes?

Comment: @Jeff No, not necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what the use-case for this is, so it's hard to say what would make a solution viable, or better than any other solution.

That said, I suggest a small alteration to the general "extract and sort" ideas already thrown around: **If we're fine making changes to the data structure, we can do our sorting in place.**

The basic implementation suggested on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Implementation) is a *partially sorted* list under-the-hood. We can pay a (hopefully) one-time *O*(*n* log(*n*)) cost to sort our heap when the first time `next()` is called, after which `next` is *O*(1). Critically, **a fully-sorted list is still a valid heap**.

Furthermore, if you consider the [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) algorithm, you can start at stage two, because *you're starting* with a valid heap.