# Algorithm to check if k'th smallest element in max-heap is bigger than given number

Tags: algorithm, heap, max-heap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How we can find kth largest element from a max-heap in O(k) time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922648/how-we-can-find-kth-largest-element-from-a-max-heap-in-ok-time)

There is a given a max-heap,
we want to find an algorithm in o(k) time complexity to check if k'th smallest element is bigger than arbitrary given number.

Comment: kth **smallest** element in a **MAX** heap?

Comment: Is it max heap and smallest kth smallest element? Finding the smallest element in a max heap can be done in only `O(n)` AFAIK (you only know it is in one of the leaves). You can find the kth largest element in a max heap however in `O(k)`

Comment: yes, Kth smallest element in a MAX heap

Comment: I don't want the kth largest element, I want an algorithm to check if kth smallest element is larger than arbitrary given number or not.

Comment: An algorithm  in O(k), even O(klogn) doesnt exists. if you are using a max-heap it means the operation getMax() and deleteMax() are the most used... Otherwise use a min heap.

Comment: @PooriaKaviani Actually your question is invalid. Of course the answer will depend on the actual data structure implementation. I suppose you mean if you implement the heap in a static array? Also can we destroy the structure of the heap when answering the query (i suppose not).

Comment: Yes, we can destroy it, the given max-heap is in binary tree.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: definitely it's not a duplicate of this question because here we are speaking about kth smallest, not largest element, and we are not required to find it.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev, You are right, I misread.

Comment: REALLY? Why was it closed? It is NOT a dupe, it is entirely different question, asking for smallest k in max heap - not largest. **VOTING TO REOPEN**