# Check if x is bigger than k-th smallest number in a min-heap

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-heap

I know this question was asked before. I read the following question:
[how to determine if the kth largest element of the heap is greater than x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922648/how-to-determine-if-the-kth-largest-element-of-the-heap-is-greater-than-x)
but I have further questions. I did not want to post in a thread that old. So:

Given a number `x` and a number `k`, check if `x` is bigger than the `k`-th smallest element in `O(k)`.

The previous question does the same thing, but with max-heaps and smaller than. That is not the problem.

Consider a binary min-heap:

```
              1
      2               3
  12    17         50  90
23,18 80,88      51,52 91,92
```

Let `x` be 19 and `k` be 6.

The 6th smallest element is 18.

If I do the algorithm in the other thread, it would check as follows:

```
1+,2+,12+,23,18+,17+,80,88,3+
```

The `+` signals when the counter is increased.

How does the algorithm know that 18 is the `k`-th smallest number, not 3?

And why does the checking of 23, 80 and 88 not interfere with `O(k)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does the algorithm know that 18 is the kth smallest number, not 3?

It doesn't matter to the algorithm - it simply counts the smaller numbers - it doesn't keep track of which one is the k-th smallest number.

If it finds more than `k` smaller numbers, it knows the k-th smallest number is smaller than `x`.

---

If we want to actually find the k-th smallest number, we'd likely need to do O(k log k) work, as we need to keep track of the candidates in order so we know which one is in the k-th position, or we could do an (expected) O(n) [quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).

> And why does the check of 13,80,88 not interfere with O(k)?

Think of it this way - each node only has 2 children, and we'll only process a node's children if it's smaller than `x`, so we can include `23` and `18` in `12`'s running time (we do a constant amount of work for `12`, including the work involved for `23` and `18`) and `17` in `2`'s running time.